# facebook - problems with FBSessionState constants

Tags: ios, facebook

I am developing an iOS app that uses Facebook login and sharing. This requires checking the active session state in various places.

The code provided by Facebook checks the current state and decides whether to open a new session. However logging the session state suggests it may be open even though a comparison with FBSessionState constants may suggest its closed.

For instance, using the following code (facebook's), even though my session state logged as a `1`, it was not equal to either `FBSessionStateOpen` or `FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended`, and opened a new session.

```
NSLog(@"facebook session state: %lu", FBSession.activeSession.state);
// log shows 1

if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

    NSLog(@"facebook session already open");
    // do stuff...

} else {
    // new session opened anyway
    NSLog(@"open new facebook session");
    /* code to open a session omitted here
    ...
    */
}
```

This, despite the constant definition shows `1 = FBSessionStateOpen`.

FBSession.h:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBSessionState) {
/*! One of two initial states indicating that no valid cached token was found */
FBSessionStateCreated                   = 0,
/*! One of two initial session states indicating that a cached token was loaded;
 when a session is in this state, a call to open* will result in an open session,
 without UX or app-switching*/
FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded        = 1,
/*! One of three pre-open session states indicating that an attempt to open the session
 is underway*/
FBSessionStateCreatedOpening            = 2,

/*! Open session state indicating user has logged in or a cached token is available */
FBSessionStateOpen                      = 1 | FB_SESSIONSTATEOPENBIT,
/*! Open session state indicating token has been extended, or the user has granted additional permissions */
FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended         = 2 | FB_SESSIONSTATEOPENBIT,

/*! Closed session state indicating that a login attempt failed */
FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed         = 1 | FB_SESSIONSTATETERMINALBIT, // NSError obj w/more info
/*! Closed session state indicating that the session was closed, but the users token
 remains cached on the device for later use */
FBSessionStateClosed                    = 2 | FB_SESSIONSTATETERMINALBIT, // "
};
```

Is this a bug or is there some reason why facebook's code should really open a new session? Should I compare against the `int` value of the state instead of the constant? Why would the logged value disagree with the constant?

...Furthermore, logging the state *after* the state is re-opened, it logs as 513 or 514, which doesn't agree with any constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the typedef enumeration of the constants, a state of `1` is `FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded`. The comment says "One of two initial session states indicating that a cached token was loaded; when a session is in this state, a call to open* will result in an open session, without UX or app-switching".

So I took that advice, the solution works well and the session is opened without UX or app switching:

```
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        NSLog(@"fb session state created token loaded.");
        [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
            if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }];
    }
    else if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {
        NSLog(@"fb session already open");
        // do stuff

    } else {
        NSLog(@"open new facebook session");
        // open new session...
    }
```